# How do I resolve: Unable to Cast due to 'Unknown Context'?

Tags: swift, generics, combine

**Scenario:** 
A function takes a generic parameter (**CovidResource**) to grab data from a server which returns a data in a particular format depending on the value of the function's parameter, **CovidResource**.

The intent is to use one (1) function to grab data from assorted endpoints in a format/endpoint.

The function returns a struct **AppleSubRegions** (in this example, one of any possible data types via generic value) in **CovidResource** format.

```
 let url = URL(string: "https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/apple/countries/CANADA")!
        countryListViewModel.getList(urlDataModel: CovidResource<AppleSubRegions>(url: url))
```

```
struct AppleSubRegions: Codable {
    let country, subregion: String
    let data: [AppleDatum]
}
```

```
import Combine
import UIKit

protocol URLResource {
    associatedtype DataModel: Decodable
    var url: URL? { get }
}

struct CovidResource<T: Decodable>: URLResource {
    typealias DataModel = T
    var url = URL(string: "https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/apple/countries/Canada")
}

// =====================================================================================================

class CountryRegionListModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var countryRegionList: [String] = []

    // Data Persistence:
    var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    func getList<Resource>(urlDataModel: Resource) where Resource: URLResource {
        let remoteDataPublisher = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: urlDataModel.url!)
            .map(\.data)
            .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { data in
                print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
              })
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .decode(type: Resource.DataModel.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        
            //.print("getList: ")
        
        remoteDataPublisher
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                switch completion {
                case .finished:
                    print("Publisher Finished")
                case let .failure(anError):
                    Swift.print("\nReceived error: ", anError)
                }
            }, receiveValue: { someValue in
                print("\n\n ---- Model: \(someValue)")
                DataSource.shared.countryName = (someValue as! AppleSubRegions).country
               
            }).store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

You can see the datatype returned is '**AppleSubRegions**':
(Notice the '**unknown context**...)?

```
(lldb) po type(of: someValue)
Covid19.TabNavView.(unknown context at $10bb96490).(unknown context at $10bb96504).AppleSubRegions
```

I can see the country, '**Canada**' via the debugger:

```
---- Model: AppleSubRegions(country: "Canada", subregions: ["Alberta", "Calgary", "Edmonton", "British Columbia", "Vancouver", "Manitoba", "New Brunswick", "Newfoundland and Labrador", "Northwest Territories", "Halifax", "Nova Scotia", "Ontario", "Ottawa", "Toronto", "Prince Edward Island", "Montreal", "Quebec", "Saskatchewan", "All", "Yukon Territory"])
(lldb) po someValue.country
"Canada"
```

I tried repeating what I did via the debugger in code:

[image]

... but as you can see, the **DataModel** isn't aware of '**country**':

Yet I can't access its members.

So I tried to cast 'someValue' to **AppleSubRegions** type:

[image]

Which crashed the compile.

**Question:** How do I convert the **CovidResource** into **AppleSubRegions** proper (Swift data item)?

---

**Suggestions tried:** 
1. Qualifying closure with

```
...receiveValue { someValue: AppleSubRegions in
```

But I got a compiler syntax error:

[image]

2. Adding an additional constraint:

[image]

But this causes another compiler error:

[image]

Comment: try `receiveValue { someValue: AppleSubRegions in`

Comment: `getList` is a generic function to any type that conforms to `URLResource` - it doesn't know anything about `AppleSubRegions`. If you want it to know about, then you'd need to constrain it further: `where Resource.DataModel == AppleSubRegions`

Comment: I tried both feedbacks which ended in compiler errors.  I'm still at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you further constrain the type to `AppleSubRegions`:

```
func getList<R: URLResource>(urlDataModel: R) where R.DataModel == AppleSubRegions {
    let remoteDataPublisher = Just(json)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .decode(type: R.DataModel.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())

    remoteDataPublisher
        .sink(
            receiveCompletion: {...}, 
            receiveValue: { someValue in
               print(someValue.country)
            }).store(in: &c)
}
```

Comment: I'm still having problems with this.  I've created a mini app (storyboard paradigm) to try to get this to work.

Comment: Restricting the R.DataMode to 'AppleSubRegions' would restrict me to 'AppleSubRegions' which defeats my intent to use one (1) network engine for MANY data models.

Comment: @FrederickC.Lee, of course it would restrict - that's what it means if you're trying to access `.country` - it means that the function "knows" about this property's existence. Otherwise, you'd need to factor it out of the function (e.g. maybe use a completion handler, or instead of creating a subscription, return the publisher and create a subscription elsewhere.